# Bootstrap Dropmenu automatically resizes on click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am building a simple navbar that has a `drop-down menu` at the far right as shown here:

[image]

The problem is that when I click the dropdown the navbar it automatically resizes as shown in the image below and this is not what I want

[image]

Here is my `navbar` code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/dashboard">
    <img
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png') }}"
      width="30"
      height="30"
      class="d-inline-block align-top"
      alt=""
    />
    App Test
  </a>

  <div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="padding: 0px">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="border: none">
        <a
          class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
          href="#"
          id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
          role="button"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          <img
            src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/fox.jpg"
            width="40"
            height="40"
            class="rounded-circle"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `navbar-expand` such as `navbar-expand-lg`.
As [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/) said:

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

And:

> For navbars that never collapse, add the .navbar-expand class on the navbar. For navbars that always collapse, don’t add any .navbar-expand class.

The `.navbar-expand-xx` with `.dropdown-menu` selectors contains `position:absolute;` which make dropdown menu look float instead of expanding the area.

After add `navbar-expand-` class, the navbar required `flex-grow-1` class on brand element to push menu button to the right. This is Bootstrap's [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand flex-grow-1" href="/dashboard">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png') }}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        App Test
    </a>

    <div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="padding: 0px;">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="border: none;">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/fox.jpg" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-circle">
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/wry5vq8h/).

Now, you may see that the dropdown menu itself is off screen. You can fix this use [menu align option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment).

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
</div>
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/wry5vq8h/1/).